# I want to add a note on product detail page in admin under "Images And Videos" tab in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, image

How can i add a note on product detail page in admin under "Images And Videos" tab in Magento 2.

Any help would be appricicated.

[image: Product Detail Page Admin]

Answer (score 1):

You can add text in `gallery.phtml` file

Override this file

> vendor/magento/module-product-video/view/adminhtml/templates/helper/gallery.phtml

Add you text on top of page

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content */
$elementName = $block->getElement()->getName() . '[images]';
$formName = $block->getFormName();
?>
<div><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add Your Text Here'));?></div>
<div class="row">
    ...
    ...
```

**OutPut:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am also trying the same way. But does it possible using UI Component  ??

Answer (score 0):

After enable the template hint path from backend `Store >> Configuration >> Advanced >> Developer >> Debug >> Enabled Template Path Hints for Admin`, you will able to identify the template path.

For gallery section, you can Override the below template file and can add your additional text here:

> vendor/magento/module-product-video/view/adminhtml/templates/helper/gallery.phtml